# bash storing command in variable

Tags: bash, unix

hey im new to bash and for some reason I cant store the output into a variable

```
#!/bin/bash
file="~/cs/cs3776/assignment2/passwd1.txt"
while read p; do

        echo "$p" | cut -d: -f1





done < passwd1.txt
```

changing the echo to

```
$a=$(echo "$p" | cut -d: -f1)
echo "$a"
```

doesnt seem to work

Comment: Besides changing the `echo` command as you have shown, what have you done to try to diagnose this? Are you getting any output at all? Are you sure that the `passwd1.txt` file has text in it? Is it formatted like `/etc/passwd`? If not, please show us what it looks like — it doesn't have to be your *actual* data, just something to illustrate the format. P.S. say `a=...`, not `$a=...`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here. The one you're seeing is that you're using a dollar sign on the variable you're assigning to -- the dollar sign is used to *get* the value of a variable, not to set it. Thus, use `a=$(echo "$p" | cut -d: -f1)` instead of `$a=$(echo "$p" | cut -d: -f1)`.

The second problem is in the assignment `file="~/cs/cs3776/assignment2/passwd1.txt"` -- the `~` needs to be expanded to the path to your home directory, but that expansion doesn't happen when it's in double-quotes. In this case, there's nothing else there that'd be expanded, so just leaving off the quotes (`file=~/cs/cs3776/assignment2/passwd1.txt`) would work. If quotes were needed for the rest of the string, it's possible to partially-quote the string (`file=~/"cs/cs3776/assignment2/passwd1.txt"`).

Comment: What you wrote about the second problem is right in general, it's good you have spotted this. In this particular case it changes nothing because `$file` is never used.